# Building a list of products from the elements in another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new in Mathematica software, and I need help with a simple exercise.

Given the list

```
list = {x, 3.2, y, 1, 2.679, 3, z, 4, -7.9};
```

I need to make some rules to generate a new list with only three elements.

- first element is the product of its symbols
- second element the product of its integers
- third element the product of its real numbers

Thus

```
newlist = {x y z, 12, -67.72512}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using rules for this task may be not very efficient, but here is a rule-based solution:

```
list /. {
    {List -> Times, _Real   -> 1, _Integer -> 1},
    {List -> Times, _Symbol -> 1, _Real    -> 1}, 
    {List -> Times, _Symbol -> 1, _Integer -> 1}
    }
```

> {x y z, 12, -67.7251}

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) in several ways:

```
GroupBy[list, Head, Apply[Times]] /@ {Symbol, Integer, Real}
```

> {x y z, 12, -67.7251}

or using a combination of `GroupBy` and[`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) (thanks: CarlWoll):

```
Lookup[{Symbol, Integer, Real}] @ GroupBy[list, Head, Apply[Times]]
```

> same result

```
RotateRight @ Values @ GroupBy[SortBy[Head] @ list, Head, Apply[Times]]
```

> same result

Alternatively, you can use [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
RotateRight[Times @@@ GatherBy[SortBy[Head] @ list, Head]]
```

> {x y z, 12, -67.7251}

Also, `Replace`:

```
Times @@@ Replace[list, {Except @ Blank @ # -> 1} & /@ {Symbol, Integer, Real}, {1}]
```

and `DeleteCases`:

```
Times @@@ (DeleteCases[list, Except@Blank@#] & /@ {Symbol, Integer, Real})
```

Comment: Lookup would be more idiomatic than mapping: `Lookup[GroupBy[list, Head, Apply[Times]], {Symbol, Integer, Real}]`

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll; great point.

Comment: Thank you @Shadowray. Hope the updated version works in general.

Comment: Duplicate symbols may change the head of the product. E.g. `{x, x, 1, 2.0}`

Comment: Whoops!! Thank you again @Shadowray. Fixed now.

Answer (score 13):

This doesn't involve any rules, but you could use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) to select the desired types, using [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through) and [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) as needed:

```
Times@@@Through@{Cases[_Symbol], Cases[_Integer], Cases[_Real]}@list
```

> {x y z, 12, -67.7251}

Answer (score 11):

A way of doing it with `Reap` and `Sow` that would work in versions as old as V5, long before newfangled functions like `GroupBy` were introduced (V.10).

```
list = {x, 3.2, y, 1, 2.679, 3, z, 4, -7.9};
Reap[
  Switch[#,
     _Symbol, Sow[#, "s"],
     _Integer, Sow[#, "i"],
     _Real, Sow[#, "r"]] & /@ list,
  {"s", "i", "r"}, 
  Times @@ #2&][[-1, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {x y z, 12, -67.7251}
> ```

Comment: There's no point in using Switch here:
Reap[ Sow[#,Head[#]]& /@ list, {Symbol, Integer, Real}, Times@@ #2&][[-1,All,1]]

Comment: @jjagmath. Yes, that is a much better way of doing it. I have updated my answer to include your version. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 10):

One approach is to select the elements you want, and then mutliply them.

```
Times @@@ {Select[list, Not[NumberQ[#]] &], 
           Select[list, IntegerQ[#] &], 
           Select[list, NumberQ[#] && Not[IntegerQ[#]] &]}
{x y z, 12, -67.7251}
```

The first one selects all the symbols (things that are not numbers), the second selects the integers, and the third selects all the reals that are not integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {x, 3.2, y, 1, 2.679, 3, z, 4, -7.9};

Times @@ Cases[list, #] & /@ {_Symbol, _Integer, _Real}
```

{x y z, 12, -67.7251}

If the sort - order of the result doesn' t matter and the list doesn' t contain "alien" elements:

```
Times @@@ GatherBy[list, Head]
```

{x y z, -67.7251, 12}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {x, 3.2, y, 1, 2.679, 3, z, 4, -7.9};
```

Using `SortBy` and `SplitBy`:

```
ReverseSort@(Times @@@ SplitBy[SortBy[#, Head], Head]) &@list

(*{x y z, 12, -67.7251}*)
```